# Свободное сочетание?

Tags: синтаксис

Являются ли данные сочетания нерасчленимыми или нет?

> Проявить уважение к директору.  Проявить смелость в этом деле.

Вроде бы "проявить" сам по себе информативно недостаточен.

Comment: Ну да, существительное нельзя изъять.

Comment: Если они несвободные, значит должна быть какая-то логичная замена в виде одного глагола (словом "уважить" еще как-никак можно заменить первую часть, но как быть с "проявить смелость"  - осмелеть, что ли).

Comment: *Осмелеть* — смысл такой, а стилистику долой. Разве всегда можно заменить? А как с "*проявить инициативу*"?

Comment: Вот потому и смущает, что не всегда получается корректно заменить, а ведь примеров много, и они похожи. Где-то "внутренний язык" противится такой замене на глагол.